# How do I track progress in a multipart upload to s3 using Go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, goamz

I am attempting to use the PutPart method provided by the goamz fork by Mitchell Hashimoto.  Sadly every time I get a part back and check the size it seems to think it is the size of the whole file and not just a chunk.

For instance

When uploading a 15m file I expect to see

```
Uploading...
Processing 1 part of 3 and uploaded 5242880.0 bytes.
 Processing 2 part of 3 and uploaded 5242880.0 bytes.
 Processing 3 part of 3 and uploaded 5242880.0 bytes.
```

Instead I see:

```
Uploading...
Processing 1 part of 3 and uploaded 15728640 bytes.
 Processing 2 part of 3 and uploaded 15728640 bytes.
 Processing 3 part of 3 and uploaded 15728640 bytes.
```

Is this due to an issue with the file.Read(partBuffer)? Any help would be much appreciated.

I am using go 1.5.1 on a mac.

```go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/mitchellh/goamz/aws"
    "github.com/mitchellh/goamz/s3"
)

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Test")

    auth, err := aws.GetAuth("XXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXX")
    check(err)

    client := s3.New(auth, aws.USWest2)

    b := s3.Bucket{
        S3:   client,
        Name: "some-bucket",
    }

    fileToBeUploaded := "testfile"
    file, err := os.Open(fileToBeUploaded)
    check(err)
    defer file.Close()

    fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
    fileSize := fileInfo.Size()
    bytes := make([]byte, fileSize)

    // read into buffer
    buffer := bufio.NewReader(file)
    _, err = buffer.Read(bytes)
    check(err)
    filetype := http.DetectContentType(bytes)

    // set up for multipart upload
    multi, err := b.InitMulti("/"+fileToBeUploaded, filetype, s3.ACL("bucket-owner-read"))
    check(err)

    const fileChunk = 5242880 // 5MB
    totalPartsNum := uint64(math.Ceil(float64(fileSize) / float64(fileChunk)))
    parts := []s3.Part{}

    fmt.Println("Uploading...")
    for i := uint64(1); i < totalPartsNum; i++ {

        partSize := int(math.Min(fileChunk, float64(fileSize-int64(i*fileChunk))))
        partBuffer := make([]byte, partSize)

        _, err := file.Read(partBuffer)
        check(err)

        part, err := multi.PutPart(int(i), file) // write to S3 bucket part by part
        check(err)

        fmt.Printf("Processing %d part of %d and uploaded %d bytes.\n ", int(i), int(totalPartsNum), int(part.Size))
        parts = append(parts, part)
    }

    err = multi.Complete(parts)
    check(err)

    fmt.Println("\n\nPutPart upload completed")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the issue here is caused by not reading the file fully. `Read` can be a little subtle:

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

So you should probably be using `ioReadFull` or (better) `io.CopyN`.

That said I think you should try switching to the official AWS Go package. They have a handy [Uploader](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/Uploader.html) which will handle all of this for you:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

func main() {
    bucketName := "test-bucket"
    keyName := "test-key"
    file, err := os.Open("example")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    sess := session.New()
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    // Perform an upload.
    result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: &bucketName,
        Key:    &keyName,
        Body:   file,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Println(result)
}
```

You can find more documentation on [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager#NewUploader).

Answer (score 0):

The data you read into `partBuffer` isn't used at all. You pass `file` into `multi.PutPart` and it reads the *entire contents* of `file`, seeking it back to the beginning as necessary and blowing away all of the work that you've done.

The minimal change to your code would be to pass `bytes.NewReader(partBuffer)` into `PutPart`, instead of `file`. `bytes.Reader` implements the `io.ReadSeeker` interface that `PutPart` needs, and will also report its size as being that of `partBuffer`.

An alternative would be to use the [io.SectionReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#SectionReader) type — instead of reading the data into a buffer yourself, you just create a series of `SectionReader`s based on `file` with the sizes and offsets that you want and pass them into `PutPart`, and they will pass the reads on to the underlying file reader. That should work just as well and cut down the code that you have to write (and error-check) considerably. It also avoids buffering a whole chunk of data in RAM unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the file part to the **multi.PutPart** method (n, **strings.NewReader** ("")) then your code would have to change some points for this to work correctly, the code below will work.

Remembering that PutPart sends part of the multipart upload, reading all the contents from r, each part, except for the last one, must be at *least 5MB in size.*
It is described in goamz docs.

Points I've changed to work correctly:

Here I am creating our headerPart with all the bytes of the file

**HeaderPart: = strings.NewReader (string (bytes)**)

Here **io.ReadFull (HeaderPart, partBuffer)** I'm reading the entire buffer part of the *make ([] byte, partSize)* command, each time it is positioned in a certain part of the file.

And when we run **multi.PutPart (int (i) +1, strings.NewReader (string (partBuffer)))**, we have to +1 because it does not calculate part 0 and instead of passing the object file, we will pass part of the Content using the *strings.NewReader* function for this.

**Check out your code below, it now works correctly.**

```
package main

import(
"bufio"
"fmt"
"math"
"net/http"
"os"
"launchpad.net/goamz/aws"
"launchpad.net/goamz/s3"
)

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
     panic(err)
    } 
}

func main() {

fmt.Println("Test")

auth := aws.Auth{
    AccessKey: "xxxxxxxxxxx", // change this to yours
    SecretKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
}

client := s3.New(auth, aws.USWest2)

b := s3.Bucket{
    S3:   client,
    Name: "some-bucket",
}

fileToBeUploaded := "testfile"
file, err := os.Open(fileToBeUploaded)
check(err)
defer file.Close()

fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
fileSize := fileInfo.Size()
bytes := make([]byte, fileSize)

// read into buffer
buffer := bufio.NewReader(file)
_, err = buffer.Read(bytes)
check(err)
filetype := http.DetectContentType(bytes)

// set up for multipart upload
multi, err := b.InitMulti("/"+fileToBeUploaded, filetype, s3.ACL("bucket-owner-read"))
check(err)

const fileChunk = 5242880 // 5MB
totalPartsNum := uint64(math.Ceil(float64(fileSize) / float64(fileChunk)))
parts := []s3.Part{}

fmt.Println("Uploading...")

HeaderPart := strings.NewReader(string(bytes))

for i := uint64(0); i < totalPartsNum; i++ {

    partSize := int(math.Min(fileChunk, float64(fileSize-int64(i*fileChunk))))

    partBuffer := make([]byte, partSize)

    n , errx := io.ReadFull(HeaderPart, partBuffer)

    check(errx)

    part, err := multi.PutPart(int(i)+1, strings.NewReader(string(partBuffer))) // write to S3 bucket part by part

    check(err)

    fmt.Printf("Processing %d part of %d and uploaded %d bytes.\n ", int(i), int(totalPartsNum), int(n))
    parts = append(parts, part)
}

err = multi.Complete(parts)
check(err)

fmt.Println("\n\nPutPart upload completed")
}
```